# GitHub Actions: Unable to find the input file

Tags: nuget-package-restore, github-actions

I'm trying here to restore the nuget packages for my solution. For that, I have written below GitHub Action:

```
name: CI

on:
  push:
  pull_request:
      branches:
      - '*'
env:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
jobs:
  ci_build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
    - name: NPM Authentication
      uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Use Node.js
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
    - name: Nuget Command
      uses: actions/checkout@master
    - uses: nuget/setup-nuget@v1
      with:
        nuget-api-key: ${{ secrets.NuGetAPIKey }}
    - run: nuget restore MyProject.sln
    - name: NuGet Tool Installer
      run: NuGetToolInstaller@0
    - name: NuGet Commad
      run: NuGetCommand@2
      env:
        restoreSolution: '$(solution)'
        selectOrConfig: 'config'
        nugetConfigPath: 'Build/NuGet.config'
    - name: VS Build
      run: VSBuild@1
      env:
        solution: '$(solution)'
        platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
        configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
        msbuildArgs: /p:AuthenticateWithRegistry=false
    - name: VS Test
      run: VSTest@2
      env:
        platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
        configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
        testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
        testAssemblyVer2: '**\*test*.dll!**\*IntegrationTests.dll!**\*UiTests.dll!**\*TestAdapter.dll!**\obj\**'
    - name: Copy Files to - $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)
      run: CopyFiles@2
      env:
        content: |
            **\bin\Project*.zip
            **\bin\**\$(buildConfiguration)\*.msi
        targetFolder: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)
        flattenFolders: true
```

And below is the error I'm getting:

> ```
> Run nuget restore Advanced.OpenLink365.sln
>
> nuget restore MyProject.sln
>
> shell: C:\Program Files\PowerShell\6\pwsh.EXE -command ". '{0}'"
>
> env:
>
> solution: **/*.sln
>
> buildPlatform: Any CPU
>
> buildConfiguration: Release
>
> NUGET: C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\nuget.exe\5.4.0\x64/nuget.exe
>
> Input file does not exist: MyProject.sln.
>
> ##[error]Process completed with exit code 1.
> ```

Additionally, I have found that there is no file availble at "C:\Program Files\Powershell\6\pwsh.EXE" &C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\nuget.exe\5.4.0\x64/nuget.exe

Also, FYR - folder structure is as below:

> - Project Repo
>
>   - .github
>
>     - workflows
>     - CI.yml
>   - Projects
>
>     - MyProject.sln
>     - ...other project files

Please let me know what I have missed here.

Thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the command to be:

```
- run: nuget restore Projects/MyProject.sln
```

Comment: So do we need to specify full path starting after `Project Repo`? Also, do you have any specific documentation where I can have all such details?

Comment: @PratikSoni It's just the way the [checkout action](https://github.com/actions/checkout#checkout-v2) works. On the README page, it says _"This action checks-out your repository under `$GITHUB_WORKSPACE`, so your workflow can access it."_. Since the `GITHUB_WORKSPACE` is the default working directory of the jobs, you just need to use the correct path when accessing the files in your repo. See [this](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/virtual-environments-for-github-hosted-runners#filesystems-on-github-hosted-runners) other reference.